# Most convenient method to switch between PSN accounts to access PS Vita content from different Playstation Stores?

Tags: psn, ps-vita

I have a Japanese PSN account, as well as a US PSN account.
On my PS3, I get the best of both world since I have access to Japanese Playstation Store as well as US Playstation Store. I can purchase and download new region specific demos and games, and use them from my both accounts.

I want to do the same on my PS Vita.
However, it seems we do not have that much freedom on PS Vita.
First of all, I cannot add a second Playstation account on PS Vita, therefore I cannot directly access a second store.
I tried to download contents on my PS3 first, and then to send it to my PS3 : I obtained an error message telling me I  could not do this because my PS3 Vita account was not the owner of that content.

I think there are two methods to get content from both Playstation Stores :
- 1 : format my PS Vita and recreate the account info (as well as network connections info, etc) for the other region every time I want to use content from a different region
- 2 : buy a new PS Vita Memory Card and save my alternate account information on this card, then save region specific content on this card. When I want to switch region, I then need to change the  small memory card (so small.. hope I won't break it.. Or lose it)
Am I correct ? Are there any restrictions or problems with these methods ?
Is there a more clever or convenient way of switching between accounts ?

Thanks for any suggestion !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have two different memory cards, one for each user, but you will need to do a factory reset each time you swtich your memory cards, see the following video, courtesy of IGN:

Comment: That is what I feared. Resetting the machine every time seems quite tedious. Thanks for making things clear though.

Comment: Yeah, but at least it's possible... You can always buy two Vitas, though :)

Comment: I am wondering, what would happen if i don't do a factory reset, for the purpose of having Japanese game Trophies in the US Account (as like you can do on the PS3/4)

Comment: If you won't do a factory reset, you wouldn't be able to log in into a different account. There's no possible way to share downloaded games between accounts on the Vita. But you can earn trophies from games in other regions.

Comment: So if i have 2 Vita's, one i downloaded a Japanese Game + DLC from the Japanese PSN and took it's memory card and swapped it with one in the other Vita that previously had a US PSN Account on it, would the Japanese game + DLC still work and i just won't be able to sign into the US PSN until i swap the memory cards back over?

Comment: No. Memory cards are account specific. You won't be able to use your "Japanese account" memory card on your "US account" memory card. There's currently no known way to play downloadable games or DLC from other regions than your account's

Answer (score 1):

Do a backup of each different region PSN account you login to a PC. Then if you want to switch, just load that specific save file. No need hastle of restoring factory settings or buying another memory card / Vita etc.

Only down side is that you must have access to a PC to switch ...